# Argument error : invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, argument-error

What this error could be about? I'm defining an age at my account model:

```
def age
    birthday = DateTime.new(year_Of_Birth.to_i, month_Of_Birth.to_i, day_Of_Birth.to_i)
    self.age = ((DateTime.now - birthday) / 365.25).to_i
  end
```

and in my view i get the following error:

ArgumentError - invalid date in the following line:

```
<dd><%= @account.age %></dd>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain all `year_Of_Birth`, `month_Of_Birth`, and `day_Of_Birth` are all non-nil values?

Comment: yes because at the model I validated them to their presence to be true

Comment: Have you tried testing this in your console?

Comment: how should I test it? I'm new to ruby and ruby-mine

Comment: What are the values for `year_Of_Birth`, `month_Of_Birth`, and `day_Of_Birth`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to test in your Rails app console:

```
birthday = DateTime.new(1991,4,2)       => Tue, 02 Apr 1991 00:00:00 +0000
DateTime.now - birthday                 => (149073456141953/17280000000)
(DateTime.now - birthday)/365.25        => 23.61926437561592
((DateTime.now - birtday)/365.25).to_i  => 23
```

This works for me. Check the params that you're setting.

Comment: i get the same results as you except in "DateTime.now - birthday" which i get : (745374204810193543/86400000000000)

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure the arguments that you're passing (year_Of_Birth.to_i, month_Of_Birth.to_i, day_Of_Birth.to_i) have something wrong, debug them and show us the values, or if you want you can try this to catch some specific error:

```
begin
 birthday = DateTime.new(year_Of_Birth.to_i, month_Of_Birth.to_i, day_Of_Birth.to_i)
 self.age = ((DateTime.now - birthday) / 365.25).to_i
rescue ArgumentError
 #your logic
end
```

Comment: I did that and it's moving back to another user with empty fields